# Is Python 2.7.13 compatible with Python 2.7.16 ? in general, are Python 2.7.1X compatible to each other?

Tags: python

Python compatibility on 2.17.x versions - Is Python 2.7.13 compatible with Python 2.7.16 ? in general, are Python 2.7.1X compatible to each other?

Answer (score 0):

All versions of python 2 are backwards-compatible

Answer (score 0):

`python2` versions are backward compatible, with some caveats mentioned at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0291/#backward-compatible-packages-modules-and-tools